# In haskell how can I uppercase a unicode character with respect to current locale

Tags: haskell, unicode

It turns out that uppercasing a character is a complicated business.  If you get out of the basic ASCII character set, the rules for uppercasing a character and lowercasing a character are actually dependent on the locale in which the application is running.

As a demo application, I am attempting to uppercase the letter 'i' (with a dot) and the letter 'i' (without a dot).  Now, in en_US, 'i' (with a dot) uppercases to 'I', and 'i' (without a dot) doesn't exist (but still uppercases to 'I').

But, if I switch to Turkish (tr_TR.UTF-8), 'i' (with a dot) must uppercase to 'İ' (also with a dot) and 'ı' (without a dot) must uppercase to 'I' (also without a dot).  Lowercase should reverse these operations.

```
iİıI --> İİII  (tr_TR.UTF-8)
iİıI --> IİII  (en_US.UTF-8)
```

Now, I can do this perfectly in C.  How can I do it in Haskell?  All of the searches that I do point me directly to Data.Char.toUpper, which is not locale-aware.  I haven't found any functions that are locale-aware in any way.

---

Here's a code sample from C.  I run it on my Linux machine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

wchar_t latin_small_sharp_s[5] = {0x00df, 0x00df, 0x0053, 0x0053, 0};
wchar_t turkish_is[5] = {0x0069, 0x0130, 0x0131, 0x0049, 0};

char multibyte_turkish_is[7] = {0x69, 0x01, 0x30, 0x01, 0x31, 0x49, 0};

void print_in_locale (const char *locale, const wchar_t *str, const size_t len) {
  wchar_t *dest = calloc(len * 2, sizeof(wchar_t));
  int i;

  if (!setlocale(LC_CTYPE, locale)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Locale %s failed with error: %s", locale, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    dest[i] = towupper(str[i]);
  }
  printf("%ls, %ls\n", str, dest);
  free(dest);
}

int main () {
  print_in_locale("de_DE.utf8", latin_small_sharp_s, 5);
  print_in_locale("tr_TR.utf8", turkish_is, 5);
  print_in_locale("de_DE.utf8", turkish_is, 5);
}
```

If you saved it to "locale_test.c", you can run it on the command line with...

```
gcc -o locale_test locale_test.c && ./locale_test
```

Comment: Did you use Turkish only as an example or do you develop a piece of software targeting Turkey?

Comment: Example.  I am working on software that we're going to release multinationally when I started running into this, and then in talking about it on G+ I got a lot of friends, including those who aren't techies, interested in the problem.  I had thought that over the weekend I would develop a piece of software that demonstrated a lot of this, but never got the chance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [`Data.Text.ICU.toUpper`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text-icu/0.6.3.5/doc/html/Data-Text-ICU.html#v%3atoUpper) function from the `text-icu` package.

> `toUpper :: LocaleName -> Text -> Text`
>
> Uppercase the characters in a string.
>
> Casing is locale dependent and context sensitive. The result may be
>   longer or shorter than the original.

Comment: That was exactly it!  It looks like for most unicode support, I don't need anything beyond the Prelude putStrLn, Data.Text.ICU (for locale-dependent upper and lowercase), and Data.Text (for building unicode strings).  Possibly also the unicode codec functions to switch between UTF-8 and internal representation.